# google maps multiple markers and polylines json

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I am attempting to create something similar to this
http://kronista.co/projects/2014/rock_al_parque/artistas_internacionales.html

This is what i have so far
http://ilg.knibbshost.co.uk/index.php/about-us/where-world/

I would like to create multiple polylines from a central point
as well as have multiple markers

At the moment i have created multiple markers but have not been able to figure out the multiple polylines yet.

To make things even more complicated i would like to pass this data via a json here is the javascript i have so far. any help would be appreciated.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
var map;

function init() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.596151, -6.309816),
        zoom: 3,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
        },
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        draggable: true,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        overviewMapControlOptions: {
            opened: false,
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [{
            "featureType": "water",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#009ee3"
            }, {
                "visibility": "on"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "landscape",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#f2f2f2"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road",
            "stylers": [{
                "saturation": -100
            }, {
                "lightness": 45
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "road.arterial",
            "elementType": "labels.icon",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "administrative",
            "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
            "stylers": [{
                "color": "#444444"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "transit",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }, {
            "featureType": "poi",
            "stylers": [{
                "visibility": "off"
            }]
        }],
    }


    var polyline;
    var lineCoordinates = [
        [51.4604728, -0.1830378],
        [44.0715858, 27.2454436]
    ];

    function addAnimatedPolyline() {
        //First we iterate over the coordinates array to create a
        // new array which includes objects of LatLng class.
        var pointCount = lineCoordinates.length;
        var linePath = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
            var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lineCoordinates[i][0], lineCoordinates[i][1]);
            linePath.push(tempLatLng);
        }

        // Defining arrow symbol
        var arrowSymbol = {
            strokeColor: '#000',
            scale: 3,
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        };

        // Polyline properties are defined below
        var lineOptions = {
            path: linePath,
            icons: [{
                icon: arrowSymbol
                //offset: '100%'
            }],
            strokeWeight: 2,
            strokeColor: '#000',
            strokeOpacity: 1
        }
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(lineOptions);

        // Polyline is set to current map
        polyline.setMap(map);

        // Calling the arrow animation function
        animateArrow();
    }

    function animateArrow() {
        var counter = 0;
        var accessVar = window.setInterval(function () {
            counter = (counter + 1) % 350;

            var arrows = polyline.get('icons');
            arrows[0].offset = (counter / 2) + '%';
            polyline.set('icons', arrows);
        }, 50);
    }


    var mapElement = document.getElementById('theworld');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

    addAnimatedPolyline();

    var locations = [
        ['ABC Books', 'New Zealand Auckland', 'Books', '140 orders processed each month', 'International Mail, Uk courier, Fulfilment', 51.4604728, -0.1830378, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png'],
        ['AIM International', 'South Africa Nampar', 'Health Supplements', '100 orders processed each month', 'Uk courier, fulfilment', 41.4604728, -0.1830378, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png']
        //['name', 'name', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 51.4604728, -0.1830378, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png'],
        //['name', 'name', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 51.4604728, -0.1830378, 'https://mapbuildr.com/assets/img/markers/solid-pin-red.png']
        ];

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        if (locations[i][1] == 'undefined') {
            description = '';
        } else {
            description = locations[i][1];
        }
        if (locations[i][2] == 'undefined') {
            telephone = '';
        } else {
            telephone = locations[i][2];
        }
        if (locations[i][3] == 'undefined') {
            email = '';
        } else {
            email = locations[i][3];
        }
        if (locations[i][4] == 'undefined') {
            web = '';
        } else {
            web = locations[i][4];
        }
        if (locations[i][7] == 'undefined') {
            markericon = '';
        } else {
            markericon = locations[i][7];
        }
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: markericon,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][5], locations[i][6]),
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            desc: description,
            tel: telephone,
            email: email,
            web: web
        });
        link = '';
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, locations[i][0], description, telephone, email, web, link);
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, title, desc, telephone, email, web, link) {
        var infoWindowVisible = (function () {
            var currentlyVisible = false;
            return function (visible) {
                if (visible !== undefined) {
                    currentlyVisible = visible;
                }
                return currentlyVisible;
            };
        }());
        iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            if (infoWindowVisible()) {
                iw.close();
                infoWindowVisible(false);
            } else {
                var html = "<div style='color:#000;background-color:#fff;padding:5px;width:150px;'><h4>" + title + "</h4><p>" + desc + "<p><p>" + telephone + "<p><p>" + email + "<p><p>" + web + "<p></div>";
                iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: html
                });
                iw.open(map, marker);
                infoWindowVisible(true);
            }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(iw, 'closeclick', function () {
            infoWindowVisible(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I don't really see what's the problem. Just create another polyline like you created the first one. Wrap this in a function so that you can call a "*createPolyline*" function for each pair of coordinates...

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of map Its really easy to create if you use Cartodb instead of gmaps.

For example:

http://vimeo.com/96235251

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84443/what-is-this-postgis-query-doing-to-show-great-circle-connections/84444#84444